# SQL subquery to find Duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns below mentioned output:

Query:

```
  SELECT
        [Customer Number],
        [Name 1],
        [Tax Number 1],
        [First telephone number],
        [Customer's credit limit],
        COUNT([Customer's credit limit]) count1
    FROM base_file
    GROUP BY
        [Customer Number],
        [Name 1],
        [Tax Number 1],
        [First telephone number],
        [Customer's credit limit]
    HAVING COUNT([Customer's credit limit]) > 1;
```

Output:

```
Customer Number Name 1  Tax Number 1    First telephone number  Customer's credit limit count1
24  Test customer 1     985743678   200000  8
29  Reliance            0   25
29  Reliance            100 25
29  Reliance            100000  25
29  Reliance            150000  25
30  Reliance Co.        985743678   200000  36
34  Test Customer 2211 3        985743678   500000  31
35  Test Customer 2211 4            1000000 17
186 test            0   21
186 test            10000000000 21
186 test            3000    21
201 XAL TEST            8000    3
211 pankaj          50000000    13
213 End Customer            10000   5
228 Datta bhai...Pune           0.01    2
228 Datta bhai...Pune           3000    2
```

Now, I want to have a subquery which shall give only with records of duplicate customers with different credit limits.
So, my final out should contain only records:

```
29  Reliance            0
29  Reliance            100
29  Reliance            100000
29  Reliance            150000
186 test            0
186 test            10000000000
186 test            3000
228 Datta bhai...Pune           0.01
228 Datta bhai...Pune           3000
```

Comment: Customer  Number| Name 1| Customer's credit limit| count1  
-----------
24| 
------------
Test customer 1| ------------------
200000| --------
8  
29| Reliance| 0| 25  
29| Reliance| 100| 25  
29| Reliance| 100000| 25  
29| Reliance| 150000| 25  
30| Reliance Co.| 200000| 36  
34| Test Customer 2211 3| 500000| 31  
35| Test Customer 2211 4| 1000000| 17  
186| Test| 0| 21  
186| Test| 10000000000| 21  
186| Test| 3000| 21  
201| XAL TEST| 8000| 3  
211| Pankaj| 50000000| 13  
213| End Customer| 10000| 5  
228| Datta bhai...Pune| 0.01| 2  
228| Datta bhai...Pune| 3000| 2

Comment: Please add this info to your question not in a comment. Just edit your question and put it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively...

```
    ;WITH    tmpBase1
                  AS ( SELECT   [Customer Number] ,
                                [Name 1] ,
                                [Tax Number 1] ,
                                [First telephone number] ,
                                [Customer's credit limit]
                       FROM     base_file
                       WHERE    EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                         FROM   ( SELECT    [Customer Number]
                                                  FROM      base_file
                                                  GROUP BY  [Customer Number]
                                                  HAVING    COUNT([Customer Number]) > 1
                                                ) T
                                         WHERE  t.[Customer Number] = base_file.[Customer Number] )
                     ),
                tmpBase2
                  AS ( SELECT   [Customer Number] ,
                                [Customer's credit limit]
                       FROM     tmpBase1
                       GROUP BY [Customer Number] ,
                                [Customer's credit limit]
                       HAVING   COUNT(*) < 2
                     )
            SELECT  *
            FROM    tmpBase1
            WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   tmpBase2
                             WHERE  tmpBase1.[Customer Number] = tmpBase2.[Customer Number] )
```

Comment: Both of these don't give desired results. I just want records with duplicate customers having different credit limit values.

Comment: @Pri I modified the script above.

Comment: Thanks...modified script gives  the desired result. However, what if the duplicate customers have three/four/five/etc different credit limits instead of two ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    t.[Customer Number],
    t.[Name 1],
    t.[Tax Number 1],
    t.[First telephone number]
FROM
(
    SELECT [Customer Number], [Name 1], [Tax Number 1], [First telephone number],
           [Customer's credit limit],
           COUNT(*) OVER (
               PARTITION BY [Customer Number], [Name 1], [Tax Number 1],
                            [First telephone number]) cnt
    FROM base_file
) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1;
```